# JAVASCRIPT - Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript

## My code have a error help me!

#### I made a code to create a screen and then show the circles, but the code is giving error. Could someone help me with this error?

```js
var blob;
var blobs = [];
var x;
var y;

window.onload = function(){
 c     = document.createElement('canvas');
 width   = 300;
 height   = 300;
 c.width   = width;
 c.height  = height;
 ctx    = c.getContext('2d');
 document.body.appendChild(c);

 setInterval(draw(), 1000/30)

 blob = new Blob(width/2, height/2, 64);
}

function draw(){
 ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
 ctx.fillstyle = 'black';
 ctx.fill();

 blob.show();
}

function Blob(x, y, r){
 this.pos = this.x, this.y = x, y;
 this.r = r;

 this.show = function(){
  ctx.fillstyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the error: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're invoking the method rather than passing a reference to a function

```
setInterval(draw(), 1000/30) //here the blob instance is still not created thus the error
```

change it to:

```
setInterval(draw, 1000/30)
```